# android: the display is abnormal when adding a listview as the head view of another listview

Tags: android, listview

I added a listview A as the head view of another listview B. Then I found the display of A is abnormal, the height of A is not large enough to show the list items.
Their layout file is:

```
    <ListView
                android:id="@+id/MyListView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:cacheColorHint="@null"
                android:divider="@drawable/mydivider" />
```

Anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: Why would you bring yourself to a world of pain like this :-) Maybe you need a change of tact, is this any better: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: This is cool, does it support cursorAdapter? I have 2 cursorAdapter for 2 listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I added a listview A as the head view of another listview B.

You cannot put a `ListView` inside another `ListView`.

If your objective is to have a single list containing the contents of multiple adapters, consider using my [`MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge). Or, since your one comment suggests that you have two `Cursors`, consider using a [`MergeCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html) with a single `CursorAdapter`.

Comment: Thank you! It seems MergeCursor is more suitable for ListAdapter than CursorAdapter, I will try MergeCursor.